# Combined buffer from 2 pointers without copy

Tags: c++, c, linux, pointers

I want to make combined buffer from 2 pointers without any copying.

Example: top and bottom are allready allocated buffers with readonly data:

```
uchar top[10]; uchar bottom[10];
```

I need something like this:

```
struct Buffer { uchar * top, * bottom; };
Buffer buffer; buffer.top = & top; buffer.bottom = & bottom;
```

and then using buffer as single array:

```
process( & buffer, size20 );
```

process is the function from some lib:

```
void process( uchar * buffer, int size );
```

Is there some approach in c/c++ to do it?

Comment: (What is C/C++?) Well, doesn't this work as it is? Your function `process`  can access both `buffer.top` and `buffer.bottom`.

Comment: process is not my func. It takes single buffer.

Comment: What is the prototype of 'process'?  (what are the types of the parameters?)  I assume uchar* and size_t or int.

Comment: If this had been C++, and `process` a template taking an iterator, you could have written something up. If it is a C function, there is not much you can do about it. And in either case you should ask yourself how much work you are prepared to spend trying to save work. Is there a net win?

Comment: It is Linux. And it is not c++ template.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't use both tags if you don't have an explicit cross-language problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to define `Buffer` such that assigning two *distinct* strings of data end up end to end. You *must* define it as

```
struct Buffer { uchar top[10], bottom[10]; };
```

and then you *must* set these values with a straight copy.

Answer (score 0):

If process looks like:

```
process(uchar* buf, size_t n);
```

You can create a single buffer that is as long as you want (20?), like this:

```
uchar buffer[20];
```

Then create top and bottom as pointers that point to the top and bottom halves of 'buffer', like:

```
uchar* top = buffer;
uchar* bot = buffer + 10;
```

or:

```
uchar* top = &buffer[0];
uchar* bot = &buffer[10];
```

now process can be called:

```
process(buffer, 20);
```

You could also do:

```
struct buffer{
    uchar top[10];
    uchar bot[10];
};

buffer buf;
buf.top = ....
buf.bot = ....

process((uchar*)&buf, 20);
```

Comment: top and bottom are allready allocated buffers with readonly data.

Comment: I want to work with them as with single buffer without any memory copying/allocating.

Comment: If there is no assurance that they are actually next to each other in memory there is no way to use them as a single buffer.  If they are guaranteed to be next to each other in memory, and in the right order, you might get by with it.

Comment: "*You could also do*" but you shall not. There might very well be a number of padding bytes between the `struct buffer`'s members `top` and `bot`. As it seems to be `char`s only packing the `struct` might help here.

Comment: with a uchar being 1 byte, I think the likelihood of padding is nil.

Comment: Yes. They have different memory addresses. Not side by side in memory.

Comment: Thanks.

I have understood that it is not impossible to do it with simple c-style pointers. Closed.

Best regards, Viktor.